# Conditional foreground color on selected DataGrid row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, selected, foreground

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `CollectionViewSource` being populated from a database. Some of these items are "active" while others are "inactive." I would like the inactive rows to have a different foreground color, which I have managed to do, but the color does not apply selected rows. It seems that the `System.HighlightTextBrushKey` overrides any attempts at changing the highlighted color. Here is the code that works for non-selected cells.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource ThemeHighlightColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource ThemeHighlightColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=active}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrchid"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=active}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

In the above case, the "inactive" rows will take on the DemiBold font, even if selected, but only unselected rows take on the DarkOrchid color. Instead, they use the `SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey` color of Black (even if I don't explicitly state this, these selected rows use the default `SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey` color of white).

I tried using a `MultiTrigger` instead of the above `DataTriggers` but I have the exact same problem (font is bold, but remains black). Here is the `MultiTrigger`:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=active}" Value="False"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrchid"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

I can't find a solution to this anywhere. Is there some way to make the foreground color on a selected row conditional on some bound value?

Comment: Did you try setting HighlightTextBrushKey to DarkOrchid in DataGrid.Resources? like this: `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="DarkOrchid"/>`

Comment: @sthotakura yes, but that changes all selected rows to Dark Orchid. I only want rows that are inactive AND selected.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this problem I created a style for the cell contents (a `TextBlock` in my case).  I placed the style in the `DataGrid.Resources`.  In your case it would look something like:

```
<Datagrid.Resouces>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="Text">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=active}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrchid"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=active}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Datagrid.Resouces>
```

From there you can use it in each cell.  This would look something like:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" 
                    ElementStyle="{StaticResource Text}" />
```

It is a bit of a pain to add a style to each of the columns you have, but this will take precedence over the `System.HighlightTextBrushKey` of the `DataGrid`.

By the way, styling each `TextBlock` this way will keep the foreground color for all conditions including selected and mouse over.  If you need different foreground colors for these conditions then you will need to add them to the `Style.Triggers` collection.